# Dependent functional JUnit tests can't share static fields

Tags: java, testing, junit, static

I have the following test (simplified for this question):

```java
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
public class ArticleTest {

    private static Article article;

    @Test
    public void testCreateArticle() {
        articleService.create("My article");
        article = articleService.findByTitle("My article");
        assertNotNull(article);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateArticle() {
        article.setTitle("New title");
        articleService.save(article);
        assertNull(articleService.findByTitle("My article"));
        article = articleService.findByTitle("New title");
        assertNotNull(article);
    }

}
```

`testCreateArticle` passes successfully, but `testUpdateArticle` fails at the first line because `article` is `null`, throwing thus an NPE (although the first test asserted that `article` wasn't `null`).

Anyone understands why? Note that I run the test with Play Framework (which loves bytecode manipulations), so this may be related somehow...

Also, I know that having dependent tests is a bad practice, but IRL, this isn't a unit test but a kind of *test scenario*, so I just wanted to give dependent tests a try to understand by myself why people don't like them ;)

But anyway, static fields are supposed to be shared between tests, am I wrong?

---

Update: I know that I could recreate an article in `testUpdateArticle()`, but the real tests are more complex (maybe I failed at creating an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...). Say I have a third test that depends on the second one (that depends on the first one), etc. The first one needs nothing special, the second one needs a created article, the third one needs a created then updated article, etc. I wanted to try to avoid redoing all DB operations each time, by keeping the state between the tests (making them dependent then).

Comment: Maybe in that case better use TestNG, it support dependent tests.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to recreate the article object before each test using the @Before annotation.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    articleService.create("My article");
}
```

That way the article object does not need to be static and makes testing easier.

NOTE: Don't forget to clean-up article in `@After` method

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    articleService.delete("My article");
}
```

Comment: You're right, this would have been the right approach in this case. The real tests are a bit more complex though, updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your behavior:

```
@FixMethodOrder
public class RemoveMeTest {
private static String string;

@Test
public void testOne() {
    string  = "foo";
}

@Test
public void testTwo() {
    System.out.println("in test two: " + string) ;
}
}
```

And the output is indeed "foo". Do you a special configurations or test runners for your test cases?

And a test case should really, really not be dependent on other test cases. I wanted to mention that, too, even if your case is more complex and others have mentioned it already ;)
Test A fails, B and C will fail too, even though they work. You change test A, runs, but B and C fails, in your example when you change the String "my article", even though they work. If C fails, you have to run A and B before, to verify that C runs again.

The worst is imo: It increases complexity which is totally unnecessary. As it is my belief: test code is as valuable as production code, refering to readability, complexity, maintainability, and so on. It's much easier to understand 10 lines of code, instead of 30 lines of code. You can trust my experience. And with experience I mean: I did it wrong a lot... and present self was very angry about (lazy) past self :P. With that said: I prefer an easy to understand test case over n db round trips, it's much cheaper in the long run...